# Perl regex matching optional phrase in longer sentence

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match an optional (possibly present) phrase in a sentence:

```
perl -e '$_="word1 word2 word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3\n" if m/(word1).*(word2)?.*(word3)/'
```

Output:

```
1:word1 2: 3:word3
```

I know the first '.*' is being greedy and matching everything up to 'word3'.  Making it non-greedy doesn't help:

```
perl -e '$_="word1 word2 word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3\n" if m/(word1).*?(word2)?.*(word3)/'
```

Output:

```
1:word1 2: 3:word3
```

There seems to be a conflict of interest here.  I would have thought Perl would match (word2)? if possible and still satify the non-greedy .*?.  At least that's my understanding of '?'.  The Perl regex page says '?' makes 1 or zero times so shouldn't it prefer one match rather than zero?

Even more confusing is if I capture the .*?:

```
perl -e '$_="word1 word2 word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4\n" if m/(word1)(.*?)(word2)?.*(word3)/'
```

Output:

```
1:word1 2: 3: 4:word3
```

All groups here are capturing groups so I don't know why they are empty.

Just to make sure the inter-word space isn't being captured:

```
perl -e '$_="word1_word2_word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4\n" if m/(word1)(.*?)(word2)?.*(word3)/'
```

Output:

```
1:word1 2: 3: 4:word3
```

Given the only match not capturing is the one between word2 and word3 I can only assume that it's the one doing the matching.
Sure enough:

```
perl -e '$_="word1_word2_word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4 5:$5\n" if m/(word1)(.*?)(word2)?(.*)(word3)/'
```

Output:

```
1:word1 2: 3: 4:_word2_ 5:word3
```

So the greedy matching is working backwards, and Perl is happy to match zero (rather than one) instance of word2.  Making it non-greedy doesn't help either.

So my question is: how can I write my regex to match and capture a possible phrase in a sentence?  My examples given here are simplistic; the actual sentence I am parsing is much longer with many words between those I am matching, so I can't assume any length or composition of intervening text.

Many thanks,
Scott

Comment: At a first glance, you select non-greedy matching for the first indiscriminate pattern `.*`, which is followed by an optional pattern (`(word2)?`) and another catch-all expression ( `.*`), the latter matching greedy again and grabbing your input which is why your capture group 2 (3) is never filled.

Comment: Instead of using the wildcard ".*", try using "\s" character class for whitespace with "+" quantifier. Like this "\s+".

Comment: It's not just perl's implementation (unless regex101 is written in perl?). [This gives the same result](https://regex101.com/r/dE7iQ2/1). And I think you got the answer in the two previous comments.

Comment: *Greedy matching is working backwards* - you know, greedy quantifier with a subpattern to follow causes *backtracking*. And the real answer is: use a tempered greedy token with a negated optional pattern up to the optional pattern: [`(word1)(?:(?!word2).)*(word2)?.*?(word3)`](https://regex101.com/r/vM9dB5/1)

Comment: *"the actual sentence I am parsing is much longer with many words between those I am matching"* It is always dangerous to abstract your example from the real data, and it would help a lot if you were to give a real example. The easiest fix is to change the regex to `/(word1)\s+(word2\s+)?(word3)/` which works fine, but I have no idea whether that would work with the real data

Comment: It'd be nice if Perl had a switch that said: "I can see that the regex contains a captured match so I'll try to satisfy that in preference to a non-captured match."  Thanks to those for clarifying the regex engine - I still find it counter-intuitive though.  Especially given that making the second `.*` non-greedy doesn't limit the backtracking.

Comment: I'm also surprised that using the possessive quantifier on `(word2)?+` doesn't work.  It shouldn't return its match to the following `.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew any chance you could convert your comment to an answer?  I'd like to vote it up.

Comment: @Scott: I added an answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### BACKGROUND: HOW LAZY AND GREEDY QUANTIFIERS WORK

You need to understand how greedy and lazy quantifiers work. Greedy ones will grab the text their patterns can match at once, and then the engine will *backtrack*, i.e. it will try to go back to the place where the greedily quantified subpattern matched the substring, trying to check if the next subpattern can be matched.

Lazy matching patterns just match the minimum characters first, and then tries to match with the rest of the subpatterns. With `*?`, it matches *zero* characters, an empty space, and then goes on to check if the next pattern can be matched, and only if it cannot, the lazy subpattern will be "expanded" to include one more character, and so on.

So, `(word1).*(word2)?.*(word3)` will match the `word2` with the first `.*` (and the second `.*` will match an empty space as the first `.*` is greedy. Although you can think that `(word2)?` is greedy and thus must be backtracked to, the answer is no, because the first `.*` grabbed all the string, and then the engine went backwards looking for the match. Since `(word2)?` matches an empty string, it always matched, and `word3` was matched first from the end of the string. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ2vL5/1) and check the *regex debugger* section.

You thought, let's use *lazy matching with the first `.\*?`*. The problem with [`(word1).*?(word2)?.*(word3)`](https://regex101.com/r/nJ2vL5/2) (that matches `word2` with the second `.*` that is greedy) is a bit different as *it could match the optional group*. How? The first `.*?` matches zero characters, then tries to match *all subsequent subpatterns*. Thus, it found `word1`, then an empty string, and *did not find the `word2` right after `word1`*. **If `word2` were right after `word1`, there would be a match with the first `.*?`.** See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJ2vL5/3).

#### SOLUTION

There are two solutions that I see at this moment, and they both consist in making the second optional group "exclusive" for the rest of the pattern, so that the regex engine could not skip it if found.

- A [**branch reset**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) [solution provided by Casimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772978/3832970) above. Its disadvantage is that it cannot be ported to many other regex flavors that do not support branch reset. See description in the original answer.
- Use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed): [`(word1)(?:(?!word2).)*(word2)?.*?(word3)`](https://regex101.com/r/vM9dB5/1). It is *less efficient than the branch reset solution*, but can be ported to  JS, Python, and most other regex flavors supporting lookaheads. How does that work? `(?:(?!word2).)*` matches 0+ occurrences of any character other than a newline (with `/s`, even including a newline) that does not start a literal character sequence `word2`. If `w` is matched, it cannot be followed with `ord2` for the construct to match. Thus, when it reaches `word2`, it stops and lets the subsequent subpattern - `(word2)?` - match and capture the following `word2`. *To make this approach more efficient**, use [**unroll the loop technique**](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop): [`(word1)[^w]*(?:w(?!ord2)[^w]*)*(word2)?.*?(word3)`](https://regex101.com/r/vM9dB5/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *branch reset* construct as a workaround:

```
 (word1)(?|.*?(word2).*?(word3)|().*?(word3))
#^            ^         ^       ^    ^---- group 3
#|            |         |       '--------- group 2
#|            |         '----------------- group 3
#|            '--------------------------- group 2
#'---------------------------------------- group 1
```

The main interest of a branch reset group `(?|...()...()|...()...())` is that capture groups have the same numbers in each branch. Instead of making the group 2 optional, you can use a first branch where the group is mandatory, and a second where it is empty *(or you can populate it with an always failing pattern and add a `?` after it)*.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your issue, you have to observe that the catch-all subexpression in your regex match material that you do not want them to:

```
 (word1).*(word2)?.*(word3)
        --
         ^--- this subexpression matches _all_ material between `word1` and `word3` in the test string, in particular `word2` if it is present

 (word1).*? (word2)? .*(word3)
        ---+--------+--
         ^       ^   ^-- this subexpression matches _all_ material between `word1` and `word3` in the test string, in particular `word2` if it is present
         |       |
         |       +------ this subexpression is empty, even if `word2` is present:
         |               - the preceding subexpression `.*?` matches minimally (ie. the empty string)
         |               - `(word2)?` cannot match for the preceding blank.
         |               - the following subexpression `.*` matches everything up to `word3`, including `word2`.
         |
         |               -> the pattern matches _as desired_ for test strings
         |                  where `word2` immediately follows `word1` without  
         |
         +-------------- this subexpression will always be empty
```

What you need is a construction that prevents the catch-all to match strings that contain `word2`. Luckily, perl's regex syntax sports the negative lookbehind that serves the purpose: for each character in the match of the catch-all subexpression, make sure that it is not preceded by `word2`.

In perl:

```
/(word1).*(word2).*(word3)|word1((?<!word2).)*word3/
```

***Caveats***

1. This might be a performance hog.
2. Note that `word2` must be a literal, as the regex engine only supports patterns with match lengths known a priori.

***Alternative solution***

Given the Caveats you might try to alter the control logic:

```
$teststring = $_;
if ($teststring =~ m/(word1).*(word2).*(word3)/) {
    print \"1:$1 2:$2 3:$3\n\";
}
else {
    # You know by now that there is no word2 between any word1, word3 occurrences 
    if ($teststring =~ m/(word1).*(word3)/) {
        print \"1:$1 2:- 3:$2\n\";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @collapsar, however I can't get the regex you provided to work: `perl -e '$_="word1_stuff_word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4 5:$5\n" if m/(word1).*(word2).*(word3)|word1((?<!word2).)*word3/'` Output: `1: 2: 3: 4:_ 5:`.  Unfortunately I'm passing the regex as a parameter to another script (swatch) so I can't use your alternate solution, but I see where you're coming from!

Comment: The regex does work, you just have to add capture groups for the parts of interest in the second alternative. This line will do the trick : `perl -e '$_="word1_stuff_word3"; print "1:$1 2:$2 3:$3 4:$4 5:$6\n" if m/(word1).*(word2).*(word3)|(word1)((?<!word2).)*(word3)/`. Note that the parens around the lookbehind expression do not establish a capture group.

Comment: *"it is just a quirky realization of non-greediness"* this doesn't help at all. `(word2)?` is a *greedy* match. `(word2)??` would be non-greedy

Comment: Got it.  Although I didn't stipulate it in the OP, it would be nice for the capture groups to be consistent.  When matching 'word2' the results are in groups 1, 2 and 3, while not matching the results are in groups 4 and 5.  Still, I appreciate your answers and explanations.

Comment: @Borodin I stand corrected and have changed the formerly incorrect analysis. I will also delete my former comment where I applied the same wrong reasoning on a test case that actually didn't support my claim. Thanks for the insight.