# Regex to get text between braces which works with occasional missing braces

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text like

```
The quick brown [fox] jumps over the lazy [dog]
```

If I use the regex

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

I get matches as

```
fox
dog
```

I am looking for a regex which works even when one of the braces are missing.

For example, if I have text like this

```
The quick brown [fox jumps over the lazy [dog]
```

I want the matches to return "dog"

Update:
Another example, if I have text like this

```
The quick brown [fox] jumps over the lazy dog]
```

I want the matches to return "fox"

The text can have multiple matches and multiple braces can be missing too :(.

I can also use C# to do substring of the results I get from regex matches.

Comment: This is only possible with balancing groups.

Comment: Does single-word match satisfy your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to match anything but `[` and `]` between the closest `[` and `]` while capturing what is inside, use

```
\[([^][]*)]
```

**Pattern details**

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ characters other than `[` and `]` (as `[^...]` is a *negated character class* and it matches all characters other than those defined inside the class) (this Group 1 value is accessed via `Regex.Match(INPUT_STRING, REGEX_PATTERN).Groups[1].Value`)
- `]` -  a literal `]` (it does not have to be escaped outside a character class)

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*)%5D&i=The%20quick%20brown%20%5Bfox%5D%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20dog%5D%0D%0AThe%20quick%20brown%20%5Bfox%5D%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20%5Bdog%5D%0D%0AThe%20quick%20brown%20%5Bfox%20jumps%20over%20the%20lazy%20%5Bdog%5D) and here is [C# demo](http://ideone.com/9CStmP):

```
var list = new List<string>() {"The quick brown [fox] jumps over the lazy dog]",
        "The quick brown [fox] jumps over the lazy [dog]",
        "The quick brown [fox jumps over the lazy [dog]"};
list.ForEach(m =>
             Console.WriteLine("\nMatch: " + 
                Regex.Match(m, @"\[([^][]*)]").Value + // Print the Match.Value
                "\nGroup 1: " + 
                Regex.Match(m, @"\[([^][]*)]").Groups[1].Value)); // Print the Capture Group 1 value
```

Results:

```
Match: [fox]
Group 1: fox

Match: [fox]
Group 1: fox

Match: [dog]
Group 1: dog
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one: `\[[^[]*?\]`

It will skip all matches if it contains `[` character.

Comment: This  is less efficient than my suggestion as lazy matching is costlier than greedy one with an appropriate character class. Also,  [it does not capture `fox`, it matches `[fox]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5b%5e%5b%5d*%3f%5c%5d&i=The+quick+brown+%5bfox%5d+jumps+over+the+lazy+dog%5d%0d%0aThe+quick+brown+%5bfox%5d+jumps+over+the+lazy+%5bdog%5d%0d%0aThe+quick+brown+%5bfox+jumps+over+the+lazy+%5bdog%5d).

Comment: I just mean that it is not the most efficient pattern for the current task. I feel you are not sure how lazy matching works. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770799/perl-regex-matching-optional-phrase-in-longer-sentence/36787675#36787675) on how lazy and greedy quantified patterns work.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Really useful! And I got a question: Is lazy always 'faster' than greedy one? Is it might be than for all these lazy checks it will require more time?

Comment: Sometimes, lazy, sometimes greedy, sometimes unrolled patterns are faster. A lot depends on the content, on the quantified pattern. In your cases, each character that is not `[` between `[` and `]` is skipped first to try to match `]`, and if it is not, the lazy pattern is expanded. In my pattern, `[^][]*` matches 0+ characters other than `[` and `]` *at once* up to the first `]`. Just go to regex101.com and test my regex and yours and pay attention to the number of steps required to match the string and see the regex debugger page.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: `\[[^\[]+?\]`

It just avoids capturing `[` with the char class.